# MapServer: Label outline in PDF print has dark thin line

Tags: labeling, mapserver, pdf, outline

I have a MapServer layer with a LABEL definition as follows:

```
CLASS
    LABEL
      MAXSCALEDENOM 1001
      MINSCALEDENOM 1
      ALIGN center
      BUFFER 0
      COLOR  [color]
      OUTLINECOLOR 255 255 255
      OUTLINEWIDTH 2
      FONT "verdana_italic"
      TYPE truetype
      SIZE [fontsize]
      MINSIZE 3
      OFFSET 0 0
      PARTIALS TRUE
      #MAXLENGTH 14
      PRIORITY 3
      WRAP '|'
      ANGLE [angle]
      FORCE TRUE
    END
  END
```

I set a an outline around the label in white color.
When I print it, it looks like this in the PDF:
[image]

The labels have a white outline but also a grayish "glow".
I would like to keep the outline but no dark glow around it.
The outline helps to make the text readable when it is above other elements in a similar color.

How can I get rid off the dark thin line around the labels?